# MySQL change value of decimal(19, 2) when insert into database

Tags: mysql, decimal, precision

I created table as you can see below:

```
create table sample_tbl
(
    decimal_column decimal(19,2) null
);
```

now, when i insert into this table with simple insert command:

```
insert into sample_tbl values (18.939);
```

MySQL stores it as **18.94**, how should i fix this problem? i want to store real value: **18.93**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value that you insert is rounded correctly to `18.94`.
What you want is to truncate the value to 2 decimal places, so use the function [`truncate()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate):

```
insert into sample_tbl values (truncate(18.939, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update sample_tbl set decimal_column =truncate(decimal_column,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If it is DECIMAL(10, 2) it will have a total of 10 numbers of which 2 are decimal values (with 2 decimal rounding meaning that 10.215 is saved as 10.22 and 10.114 becomes 10.11).
2. If it is DECIMAL(10) it will not have any decimal values and be rounded to an integer.
3. If you use FLOAT or DOUBLE PRECISION you don't have to specify the number of decimal values but it has its own flaws.

Comment: I think third item is very bad feature.

Comment: the truncate command should be a good solution for your question.